# Are Trigger.IO push notifications available with Kinvey?

Tags: parsing, trigger.io

I know that Trigger.IO sports push notification integration with Parse, how about Kinvey? If so, how would that look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently only Parse native push notifications are supported, however a native plugin (http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/native/index.html) could be written to support other platforms such as Kinvey.